# Cloud Effect In Blender to Unity

Tags: particles, unity, shape-keys, displacement

Hi I'm trying to create 3D clouds in Blender to be used in Unity. Imagine the bubbly-like fx of the flying nimbus in Dragon Ball.  Not really sure what the best approach is.  I've tried using displacement modifiers and get decent results in Blender.  But exporting to Unity is a no go.  Are shape keys my only option? If so, what's a good way to achieve what I'm after using shape keys?

Comment: Hello, could you add an example of what these clouds look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a cube, subdivide and smooth it:

[image]

Give it several shapekeys:

[image]

In *Object* mode, select a shapekey, push its *Value* up to 1 and sculpt:

[image]

Sculpt the other shapekeys, animate them:

[image]

Or you could create your mesh with metaballs that you convert to mesh:

[image]

Then give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Cloud* texture and an empty as *Object*:

[image]

In the *Displac*e modifier, save several versions *As Shapekeys*:

[image]

Now you can animate the shapekeys, also sometimes do some *Shrink/Fatten* to inflate the cloud a bit:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect thank you!